# is it possible to create subform and displaygroup without fieldset on zend forms?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-sub-form

is it possible to create subform and displaygroup without fieldset on zend forms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why to do this?
This is helpful accessibility feature?

However, You may do this in many ways, e.g. subclassing `Zend_Form` and setting your own decorators, or using `getDecorators()`, `addDecorator()` `setDecorators()` or `removeDecorator()` methods.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.

You can override the loadDefaultDecorators Zend_Form original method in your particular form like this:

```
public function loadDefaultDecorators() {
    parent::loadDefaultDecorators();

    // remove the 'fieldset' decorator from all subforms
    $subforms = $this->getSubForms();
    foreach($subforms as $subform) {
        $subform->removeDecorator('Fieldset');
    }

    return $this;
}
```

This may be helpful when you load subforms dynamically, based on e.g a selected option from a select list.
Hope this will help someone.